# Set each coefficient to 0 simultaneously

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

Here is a simple problem where I want to estimate the center manifold using a series expansion. I want to solve for the coefficients:

```
adot[a_, b_] := -a^2 + α a b
bdot[a_, b_] := a^2 - α a b - b
bseries[a_] := Sum[Subscript[b, n] a^n, {n, 0, 3}]
CoefficientList[bdot[a, bseries[a]] - D[bseries[a], a] adot[a, bseries[a]], a]
```

At this point, I'd like to set each of coefficients to zero simultaneously. Is there a smarter way to do this, rather than just copy and paste each of them into to solve and set them to 0? I'd imagine there is, thanks for the help.

Comment: I would suggest making alpha a parameter of the function `adot` and `bdot` as well - global variables are going to give you lots of trouble. If you wrap the final calculation in with, `With[{a=0,b=0},CoefficientList[...]]`, you can quickly change the values used for that calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated to include more details**

I would use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) instead of [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum) here. First your input:

```
adot[a_,b_]:=-a^2+α a b
bdot[a_,b_]:=a^2-α a b-b

lhs[b_]:=bdot[a,b]-D[b,a] adot[a,b];
```

Now, let's take the series expansion of `b[a]`:

```
ansatz = Series[b[a], {a, 0, 4}];
ansatz //TeXForm
```

> $b(0)+a b'(0)+\frac{1}{2} a^2 b''(0)+\frac{1}{6} a^3 b^{(3)}(0)+\frac{1}{24} a^4
>    b^{(4)}(0)+O\left(a^5\right)$

Putting the `ansatz` into the expression that should be 0:

```
ser = lhs[ansatz];
ser //TeXForm
```

> $-b(0)+a \left(-\alpha  b(0) b'(0)-b'(0)-\alpha  b(0)\right)+a^2 \left(-\alpha  b(0)
>    b''(0)-\frac{b''(0)}{2}-\alpha  b'(0)-b'(0) \left(\alpha  b'(0)-1\right)+1\right)+a^3
>    \left(-\frac{1}{2} \alpha  b(0) b^{(3)}(0)-\frac{1}{6} b^{(3)}(0)-\frac{1}{2} \alpha 
>    b''(0)-\frac{1}{2} \alpha  b'(0) b''(0)-b''(0) \left(\alpha  b'(0)-1\right)\right)+a^4
>    \left(-\frac{1}{6} \alpha  b(0) b^{(4)}(0)-\frac{1}{24} b^{(4)}(0)-\frac{1}{6} \alpha 
>    b^{(3)}(0)-\frac{1}{2} \alpha  b''(0)^2-\frac{1}{6} \alpha  b^{(3)}(0) b'(0)-\frac{1}{2} b^{(3)}(0)
>    \left(\alpha  b'(0)-1\right)\right)+O\left(a^5\right)$

We want to set each coefficient to 0, and [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) is capable of doing this without further preprocessing. All we need to do is to figure out what the unknowns are, which in this case are `{b[0], b'[0], b''[0], ...}`. We can extract these from `ser` using:

```
unknowns = Cases[ser, (b | Derivative[_][b])[0], Infinity] //Union;
unknowns //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{b(0),b'(0),b''(0),b^{(3)}(0),b^{(4)}(0)\right\}$

Finally, we can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) to find the unknowns:

```
sol = First @ Solve[ser == 0, unknowns];
sol //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{b(0)\to 0,b'(0)\to 0,b''(0)\to 2,b^{(3)}(0)\to -6 (\alpha -2),b^{(4)}(0)\to 24 \left(\alpha ^2-7
>    \alpha +6\right)\right\}$

Inserting these unknowns into the `ansatz`:

```
res = ansatz /. sol;
res //TeXForm
```

> $a^2+(2-\alpha ) a^3+\left(\alpha ^2-7 \alpha +6\right) a^4+O\left(a^5\right)$

Inserting the ansatz into the expression:

```
lhs[res] //TeXForm
```

> $O\left(a^5\right)$

*Another method*

It is also possible to use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) without specifying the unknowns, although it may not be completely robust:

```
sol2 = First @ Solve[CoefficientList[ser, a] == 0];

res2 = ansatz /. sol2;
res2 //TeXForm
```

> $a^2+(2-\alpha ) a^3+\left(\alpha ^2-7 \alpha +6\right) a^4+O\left(a^5\right)$

Comment: Can you possibly explain the syntax in the line after Ansatz?

Comment: @Gregory See update.

Comment: `SolveAlways[]`, can be used instead: `SolveAlways[lhs[Series[b[a], {a, 0, 4}]] == 0, a]`

Comment: @CarlWoll, the Derivative[_][b] tells Mathematica to solve for any derivative that it sees of b?